Selecting Flat Parts of a Curve
I'm trying to extract the weights of the flat parts of this curve.
plot(Unsubtracted.Weight ~ Sample.Temperature, data = tga.data, pch=19,
     ylim = c(-1,3))

So the parts at ca 2.4mg and ca 1mg ... I want to get the mean of these two flat parts of the curve.
I've tried the following code,
threshold <- 0.1  # Adjust threshold as needed

# Calculate rolling difference with window 200
rolling_diff <- abs(diff(tga.data$Unsubtracted.Weight, 1))

# Initialize empty list for flat section indices
flat_sections <- list()

# Loop to identify flat section indices
start_idx <- 1
for (i in 2:length(rolling_diff)) {
  if (rolling_diff[i] < threshold) {
    # Flat section continues
  } else {
    # End of flat section
    flat_sections[[length(flat_sections) + 1]] <- c(start_idx, i - 1)
    start_idx <- i
  }
}

# Check for last flat section at the end
if (rolling_diff[length(rolling_diff)] < threshold) {
  flat_sections[[length(flat_sections) + 1]] <- c(start_idx, length(tga.data$Unsubtracted.Weight))
}

# Calculate mean weight of each flat section
flat_means <- lapply(flat_sections, function(i) mean(tga.data$Unsubtracted.Weight[i[1]:i[2]]))

which doesn't give me two weights ... instead I get a number of different values depending upon the settings of my threshold value, and the value of the window in the diff function.
Is there a better way of doing it?
Data
dput of every 50th row, and only 2 columns of the data frame:
tga.data = data.frame(Unsubtracted.Weight = c(2.519903, 2.480581, 2.453806, 2.440516, 2.439226, 2.434226, 2.428516, 2.424839, 2.422839, 2.421839, 2.420419, 2.419258, 2.418258, 2.41729, 2.416645, 2.415677, 2.415097, 2.414194, 2.413032, 2.412516, 2.412806, 2.411839, 2.410677, 2.409935, 2.408355, 2.407452, 2.406323, 2.405419, 2.404355, 2.403355, 2.40271, 2.401839, 2.401, 2.400419, 2.400032, 2.399452, 2.39871, 2.397581, 2.39671, 2.395806, 2.395097, 2.394387, 2.393613, 2.386, 2.367258, 2.347581, 2.324, 2.287097, 2.230484, 2.144806, 2.016871, 1.846968, 1.639097, 1.408452, 1.172484, 0.960161, 0.873258, 0.873065, 0.873226, 0.874194, 0.87529, 0.875452, 0.876613, 0.876258, 0.877032, 0.877355, 0.878129, 0.878645, 0.879774, 0.880194, 0.880452, 0.881419, 0.882226, 0.882935, 0.883806, 0.884419, 0.885032, 0.885581, 0.886387, 0.887, 0.887645), Sample.Temperature = c(29.82, 29.95, 30, 30, 36.48, 53.15, 69.83, 86.5, 103.17, 119.82, 136.49, 153.16, 169.82, 186.48, 203.15, 219.83, 236.49, 253.15, 269.82, 286.48, 303.16, 319.82, 336.49, 353.15, 369.82, 386.49, 403.15, 419.82, 436.48, 453.15, 469.82, 486.48, 503.15, 519.81, 536.48, 553.15, 569.81, 586.48, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600.21, 616.59, 633.26, 649.93, 666.6, 683.26, 699.92, 716.6, 733.26, 749.93, 766.6, 783.26, 799.92, 816.59, 833.25, 849.92, 866.59, 883.25, 899.92, 916.59, 933.25, 949.91, 966.57, 983.23, 999.68, 999.99, 1000.01, 1000.01, 999.99, 1000, 999.99, 1000, 1000, 999.99, 1000, 1000))


Where do I find tga.data? Your question misses toy data.

Hi @Friede it's the output from dput ... posted into the question.

Changed it, now easy to c&p. Added a mostly vectorized answer, only a few lines long.

Ha, just noticed.  I did a simple dput by following the 'how to post in R' but next time it will be better to do what you did in your edit.  So, thanks ...

I think that a better approch would be to indentify the segments where the change is minimal. Do given this data
Unsubtracted.Weight <- c(2.519903, 2.480581, 2.453806, 2.440516, 2.439226, 2.434226, 2.428516, 2.424839, 2.422839, 2.421839, 
                         2.420419, 2.419258, 2.418258, 2.41729, 2.416645, 2.415677, 2.415097, 2.414194, 2.413032, 2.412516, 
                         2.412806, 2.411839, 2.410677, 2.409935, 2.408355, 2.407452, 2.406323, 2.405419, 2.404355, 2.403355, 
                         2.40271, 2.401839, 2.401, 2.400419, 2.400032, 2.399452, 2.39871, 2.397581, 2.39671, 2.395806, 
                         2.395097, 2.394387, 2.393613, 2.386, 2.367258, 2.347581, 2.324, 2.287097, 2.230484, 2.144806, 
                         2.016871, 1.846968, 1.639097, 1.408452, 1.172484, 0.960161, 0.873258, 0.873065, 0.873226, 0.874194, 
                         0.87529, 0.875452, 0.876613, 0.876258, 0.877032, 0.877355, 0.878129, 0.878645, 0.879774, 0.880194, 
                         0.880452, 0.881419, 0.882226, 0.882935, 0.883806, 0.884419, 0.885032, 0.885581, 0.886387, 0.887, 
                         0.887645)
Sample.Temperature <- c(29.82, 29.95, 30, 30, 36.48, 53.15, 69.83, 86.5, 103.17, 119.82, 136.49, 153.16, 169.82, 186.48, 203.15, 
                        219.83, 236.49, 253.15, 269.82, 286.48, 303.16, 319.82, 336.49, 353.15, 369.82, 386.49, 403.15, 419.82, 
                        436.48, 453.15, 469.82, 486.48, 503.15, 519.81, 536.48, 553.15, 569.81, 586.48, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 
                        600, 600.21, 616.59, 633.26, 649.93, 666.6, 683.26, 699.92, 716.6, 733.26, 749.93, 766.6, 783.26, 
                        799.92, 816.59, 833.25, 849.92, 866.59, 883.25, 899.92, 916.59, 933.25, 949.91, 966.57, 983.23, 999.68, 
                        999.99, 1000.01, 1000.01, 999.99, 1000, 999.99, 1000, 1000, 999.99, 1000, 1000)

length_to_use <- min(length(Unsubtracted.Weight), length(Sample.Temperature))
Unsubtracted.Weight <- Unsubtracted.Weight[1:length_to_use]
Sample.Temperature <- Sample.Temperature[1:length_to_use]

tga.data <- data.frame(Sample.Temperature, Unsubtracted.Weight)

plot(Unsubtracted.Weight ~ Sample.Temperature, data = tga.data, pch=19, ylim = c(-1,3))


you can then identify the segment and then do the necessary extraction and mean computations.
diffs <- abs(diff(tga.data$Unsubtracted.Weight))

threshold <- 0.01
flat_sections <- which(diffs < threshold)

flat_start <- c()
flat_end <- c()

i <- 1
while (i < length(flat_sections)) {
  start <- flat_sections[i]
  while (i < length(flat_sections) && flat_sections[i + 1] == flat_sections[i] + 1) {
    i <- i + 1
  }
  end <- flat_sections[i]
  flat_start <- c(flat_start, start)
  flat_end <- c(flat_end, end)
  i <- i + 1
}

flat_means <- sapply(1:length(flat_start), function(i) {
  mean(tga.data$Unsubtracted.Weight[flat_start[i]:flat_end[i]])
})

print(flat_means)


which gives
> print(flat_means)
[1] 2.4108065 0.8791627


that works thanks.  I needed to adjust the threshold for my full data set.  Will leave it open 24hrs for others to come up with suggestions.

Based on the simple idea of comparing the absolute values of the differences to a tolerance, we can do:
Edit
2024-05-26
Wrapped in a function. Included scale which makes setting tol more robust.
const1D = \(x, tol = .01) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(x), is.numeric(tol))
  b = abs(diff(scale(x))) <= tol
  o = b[c(TRUE, !b[-length(b)] == b[-1L])]
  i = 1L + which(diff(b) != 0L)
  split(x, cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% i))[o]
}
vapply(const1D(tga.data$Unsubtracted.Weight), mean, numeric(1L))

Code
tol = .01
b = abs(diff(tga.data$Unsubtracted.Weight)) <= tol
o = b[c(TRUE, !b[-length(b)] == b[-1L])]
i = 1L + which(diff(b) != 0L)
l = with(tga.data, split(Unsubtracted.Weight, 
                         cumsum(seq_along(Unsubtracted.Weight) %in% i)))
vapply(l[o], mean, numeric(1L))
#>         1         3 
#> 2.4108065 0.8798155

Plot
with(tga.data, plot(x = Sample.Temperature, y = Unsubtracted.Weight,
                    col = c('red','blue')[b+1L], pch = ".", cex = 3L))



Note
More sophisticated approaches would involve change-point detection algorithms. Bayesian versions might be a good idea. For reference, have a look at beast() or beast.irreg() from {Rbeast}. Probably, at first sight, you will find the list of arguments (and the help file) overwhelmeing. If all your data series are single S-shaped  curves (sigmoid(x) or, more precisly, -sigmoid(x) functions), this might be shooting at sparrows with cannons. Nonetheless, you will need to find a way to exclude the inflection points then, as those functions have exactly one.

thanks for the reference to Beast ... may use it in the future

I think a good approach to find the breakpoints is a segmented linear model, so here is an example of that.
tga.data = data.frame(y_weight = c(2.519903, 2.480581, 2.453806, 2.440516, 2.439226, 2.434226, 2.428516, 2.424839, 2.422839, 2.421839, 2.420419, 2.419258, 2.418258, 2.41729, 2.416645, 2.415677, 2.415097, 2.414194, 2.413032, 2.412516, 2.412806, 2.411839, 2.410677, 2.409935, 2.408355, 2.407452, 2.406323, 2.405419, 2.404355, 2.403355, 2.40271, 2.401839, 2.401, 2.400419, 2.400032, 2.399452, 2.39871, 2.397581, 2.39671, 2.395806, 2.395097, 2.394387, 2.393613, 2.386, 2.367258, 2.347581, 2.324, 2.287097, 2.230484, 2.144806, 2.016871, 1.846968, 1.639097, 1.408452, 1.172484, 0.960161, 0.873258, 0.873065, 0.873226, 0.874194, 0.87529, 0.875452, 0.876613, 0.876258, 0.877032, 0.877355, 0.878129, 0.878645, 0.879774, 0.880194, 0.880452, 0.881419, 0.882226, 0.882935, 0.883806, 0.884419, 0.885032, 0.885581, 0.886387, 0.887, 0.887645), 
                      x_temp = c(29.82, 29.95, 30, 30, 36.48, 53.15, 69.83, 86.5, 103.17, 119.82, 136.49, 153.16, 169.82, 186.48, 203.15, 219.83, 236.49, 253.15, 269.82, 286.48, 303.16, 319.82, 336.49, 353.15, 369.82, 386.49, 403.15, 419.82, 436.48, 453.15, 469.82, 486.48, 503.15, 519.81, 536.48, 553.15, 569.81, 586.48, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600.21, 616.59, 633.26, 649.93, 666.6, 683.26, 699.92, 716.6, 733.26, 749.93, 766.6, 783.26, 799.92, 816.59, 833.25, 849.92, 866.59, 883.25, 899.92, 916.59, 933.25, 949.91, 966.57, 983.23, 999.68, 999.99, 1000.01, 1000.01, 999.99, 1000, 999.99, 1000, 1000, 999.99, 1000, 1000))

library(segmented)

plot(tga.data$x_temp,tga.data$y_weight)
(tga_lm <- lm(y_weight ~ x_temp,data=tga.data))

(seg_tga_lm <- segmented(tga_lm,npsi = 2))

(x_break_points_found <- seg_tga_lm$psi[,2])

plot(seg_tga_lm)
abline(v=x_break_points_found)

library(tidyverse)

(summary_info <- 
mutate(tga.data,
       grp=cut(x_temp,breaks=c(
         -Inf,
         x_break_points_found,
         Inf),
               include.lowest=TRUE)) |> 
  group_by(grp) |> summarise(mean_y = 
                               mean(y_weight),
                              sd = sd(y_weight),
                              count = length(y_weight)))

summary_info$mean_y
# 2.4046728 1.5984056 0.8798155


Therefore the values of interest are 2.4046728 and 0.8798155

An important note is that segmented::segmented() needs npsi or psi to bet set a priori. library(dplyr) seems to be enough to run your code; a whole tidy-verse is not needed.

the question as posed allowed for visual inspection; vs npsi.
